# Get full query string in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

As a PHP programmer I'm used to using $_GET to retrieve the HTTP query string... and if I need the whole string, theres loads of ways to do it.

In ASP however, I can't seem to get the query.

Here is the code for news.aspx (embedded in some HTML):

```
<%                             
    string URL = "http://www.example.com/rendernews.php?"+Request.Querystring;
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string data = wc.DownloadString(URL);
    Response.Output.Write(data);
%>
```

I am fetching a PHP script's output from a remote server, and this works perfectly without the Request.Querystring.

The issue is that I'm trying to get the full query string on the first line: Request.Querystring. I am getting an error "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*" which basically means that Request.Querystring doesn't exist.

Any idea what the problem is here? How can I get that query string so when index.aspx is called like http://test.com/news.aspx?id=2 my script fetches http://www.example.com/rendernews.php?id=2

Comment: Does it always fail, or is there edge cases like no get variables defined?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Try [`Request.Url.Query`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want the raw querystring as a string.

Answer (score 19):

This should work fine for you.

Write this code in the `Page_Load` event of the page.

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/rendernews.php?id=" + ID);
```

Answer (score 11):

`Request.QueryString` returns you a collection of Key/Value pairs representing the Query String. Not a String. Don't think that would cause a Object Reference error though. The reason your getting that is because as Mauro pointed out in the comments. It's QueryString and not Querystring.

Try:

```
Request.QueryString.ToString();
```

or

```
<%                                 
    string URL = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri 
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string data = wc.DownloadString(URL);
    Response.Output.Write(data);
%>
```

Same as your code but [`Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx) will return the full path, including the query string.

Comment: With that I get:
"'System.Web.HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Querystring' and no extension method 'Querystring' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpRequest'"
and when I try adding System.Web before it, I get "The type or namespace name 'Request' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly?) "

Comment: Might want to make sure you aren't overriding Request somewhere.  I have something using Request.Querystring[.ToString()] in production and it works flawlessly.

Comment: isnt it QueryString and not Querystring? code above looks like c# - remember case sensitivity

Comment: In my case, this is exactly what I want to avoid, because ToString() is buggy in the **** old version of the .NET framework that I'm forced to use.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Request.QueryString.ToString()` to get full query string, like this:

```
string URL = "http://www.example.com/rendernews.php?"+Request.Querystring.ToString();
```

Comment: This returns the name of the class.

Comment: @Allov I have tested that, and it did returned the query string correctly, and in fact even without .ToString() it will work when concatenating with a string

Comment: It didn't work in .Net 4. Possibly it up votes are for other versions of .Net.

Comment: It is actually changing & for &amp; so it renders it unusable. Request.Url.Query is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your example, and while Request.QueryString is not convertible to a string neither implicit nor explicit still the .ToString() method returns the correct result.

Further more when concatenating with a string using the "+" operator as in your example it will also return the correct result (because this behaves as if .ToString() was called).

As such there is nothing wrong with your code, and I would suggest that your issue was because of a typo in your code writing "Querystring" instead of "QueryString".

And this makes more sense with your error message since if the problem is that QueryString is a collection and not a string it would have to give another error message.

Answer (score -1):

just a moment ago, i came across with the same issue. and i resolve it in the following manner.

```
Response.Redirect("../index.aspx?Name="+this.textName.Text+"&LastName="+this.textlName.Text);
```

with reference to the [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString)

Comment: Never never never build URLs like this in any framework or programming language. Use URL builders. They take care of encoding for you, which the code above doesn't do.