# Accessing the query string value using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url

I have been trying to find the question to my answer but I'm unable to and finally I'm here. What I want to do is access the value passed to a webpage (`GET`, `POST` request) using `asp.net`. To be more clear, for example:

URL: `http://www.foobar.com/SaleVoucher.aspx?sr=34`

Using `asp.net` I want to get the `sr` value i.e `34`.

I'm from the background of `C#` and new to ASP.NET and don't know much about `ASP.NET`.

Thanx.

Comment: In that question is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter

Comment: @luk2302 lol I needed to type `ASP.NET`

Comment: @KamranAhmed LOL, yes, because you changed the tags/topic of your question after we answered, that is not nice nor should you complain afterwards.

Comment: U can find the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you refer to this [QueryString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879773/get-full-query-string-in-c-sharp-asp-net)

Here he says how to access the query string using:

```
Request.Url.Query
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not called a Header, but the **Query String**.

the object `document.location.search` will contain that and the javascript to get any query string value based on the key would be something like:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

code from other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/28004