# Request query is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

I can't get my request params...

I do a request with ajax by POST method to my services page, in my browser console, the request i well sended like :

```
localhost/Services/?target=test&action=list&from=test
```

Send like :

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action(Url.Content("../Services"))',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: "target="+$(this).attr('id')+"&action=list&from=test", 
                    dataType: 'string',
                    success: OnSuccess
                });
```

In my controller, I ve tried :

```
var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
var q = context.Request.QueryString; //empty
var q2 = context.Request.Url.Query; //empty
// or
var id = Request.QueryString["target"].ToString(); //error - sample on the following link
```

[Get full query string in C# ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879773/get-full-query-string-in-c-sharp-asp-net)

What s wrong ?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: may be this helps you
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["id"]

Comment: ActionResult(string id){  return view();} use this and check whether you are getting the value for id or not.

Comment: i have no error just my request is empty in my c# controller

Answer (score 0):

check your global.ascx.cs file for routes. Looks like you dont have the route registered. Check this method RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

Answer (score 0):

I ve found, it was just like :

```
var target = Request["target"];
```

If that can help someone ^^