# Get all parameters in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have to create a WebAPI which fit the URL :

 http://server/share/pa/repos?file=Ring#filter=path|/A6/**ERE**/**50-001**|
and get elements into pipes => "**ERE**" and "**50-001**"

I tried this :

```
[Route("share/pa/{*endUrl}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Sharing([FromUri] string endUrl)
{ 
}
```

endUrl variable contains only "repos"
and Request.RequestUri.Query contains only "?file=Ring"

Can you have an idea to get elements "**ERE**" and "**50-001**" or entire requested url ?

Comment: If you want to get the entire query string, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1879773/9363973) is your answer

Comment: @MindSwipe not in this case, it isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything after the `#` (the fragment) is *client-side only* and never goes to the server. So no: you can't do that at the server; you *can* access and process it client-side if needed, though.